# Minimizing latency w/ web-based, live audio capture and broadcast

Tags: rtmp, http-live-streaming, live-streaming, wowza, icecast

I'm having trouble achieving low latency when doing web based capture/recording of user audio (from microphone, line-in), then live broadcasting that audio out to our listeners. Essentially a web based audio broadcasting platform but low, <2 second delays from when the broadcaster speaks to when the listeners hears it are essential.

I started with Icecast, but even locally I can't seem to get delays under a few seconds. That doesn't even factor in having to capture a user's audio, then to send it back to the server for streaming.

Really I see 3 main pieces:

1. Web based audio capture (w/ Flash probably?) that sends user audio to:
2. Media Server (something like Icecast or Wowza)
3. Player for actual listening (HTML5 w/ fallback on Flash)

So my question is how do I optimize this process to achieve low delays and still have the flexibility to stream to any device? Are there any best practices as to what server, codecs, etc to use?

Comment: Are you encoding just speech?  Or do you need to do music as well?  What level of audio quality do you need to achieve?

Comment: Just speech mostly, some music but I can sacrifice quality if it means less delay. 48kbps would do

Comment: I can guarantee you don't want to use HLS. It's just not useful for low-latency.

Answer (score 1):

Icecast is supposed to be a streaming server and it goal isn't to achieve low-latency. It is completely normal that you will have a latency of about 5 seconds using Iecast and you can't really do much about it.
HLS is even worse for your needs, since it contains of little segments and each segment has a duration that should not be lower than 3 seconds, meaning that you will definitely have a latency higher than 3 seconds.

If you really need low-latency take a look at [Mumble](https://github.com/mumble-voip/mumble), which uses the [Opus](https://opus-codec.org/) codec.